# OpenLayers 6.4.3 Not Working In Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm trying to display a very simple map in openlayers.  I have the correct stylesheet included and I don't get what's wrong.  How does one go about a very simple openlayers component in Angular?

I do have a template with the map element, yes.  I don't think it's any trivial error, but what do I know.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'core-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.sass']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var map = new Map({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM()
        })
      ],
      target: 'map',
      view: new View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You might need to set the target in afterViewInit instead of ngOnInit, I think the reason why is not working is that at ngOnInit the div which is supposed to display the map is not initialized so if you set the target in ngOnInit it won't produce any effect. Everything else looks fine (Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular10-openlayers?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts5)

Comment: It was ridiculous.  I needed to set a fixed size in the CSS for the map.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :D

Comment: In my case I needed to install more components:

    npm install @types/ol